# Error in React - following tutorial from 2019 is this an outdated issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Trying to get some Card components load up on site - however when I add  to the root line it comes up with an error (removing the  does make my site work fine but it dosnt load the card component) New to react so not sure if this is an outdated way.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JIup.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's in the `Card` component, but you can try something like this:

1. Move `<Card />` component to `<App />`'s component body
2. Refactor your `root` as follows

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: Worked spot on thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think something more like [this](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/15/react-18-adds-new-root-api.html#the-new-root-api) is what you want.

Copied from link:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from 'App';
import Card from './Cards/CardsUI'

const container = document.getElementById('root');

// Create a root.
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);

// Initial render -- Render your card here. 
root.render(<Card />);
```